# mysql: unknown variable 'login-path=develop' via ssh

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, ssh, command

I'm trying to execute below mysql command via ssh, of course this command works fine on server A, and I'm trying to execute it from server B via ssh.

```
ssh accountId@serverA "(cd dir1/dir2/; mysql --login-path=develop)"
```

but it fails with

```
mysql: unknown variable 'login-path=develop
```

does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Have you set up "mysql" as an alias or shell function on serverA? Or maybe a shell script which invokes the real mysql program?

Comment: @Kenster it's an alias. And the command itself works fine on serverA, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: What is "mysql" aliased to on serverA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause and fixed!!! I'm posting it for someone who might suffer from similar problem.

My problem was several mysql binaries on serverA. The 'mysql' binary, one that I executed on serverA and from serverB via ssh were different. So I modified the command to use absolute path for mysql and it works fine now.

```
ssh accountId@serverA "(cd dir1/dir2/; /user/bin/mysql --login-path=develop)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Manual page for `bash` explains the meaning of the braces as:

> `(list)`
>
> list is executed in a **subshell environment** (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not  remain  in  effect after the command completes.  The return status is the exit status of list.

This means that you are executing the commands on the machine A. If you really want to execute the commands in the subshell on remote machine, you need to escape the braces:

```
ssh accountId@serverA "\(cd dir1/dir2/; mysql --login-path=develop\)"
```

if you don't know what is it, just remove them. In this case, they do not matter:

```
ssh accountId@serverA "cd dir1/dir2/; mysql --login-path=develop"
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Double-quoted parentheses aren't special to the local shell. SSH will get the entire string including the parentheses.

Comment: @Kenster I see ... you are probably right. There will be some other problem.

Comment: @Jakuje Executing the commands on server A, that's what I'm trying to.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who runs into the same problem as I did, check your bash `alias` file. I forgot I added this to mine recently:

```
alias mysql='mysql --login-path=local -A'
```

So when I ran `mysql --login-path=local -A` I was actually running:

```
mysql --login-path=local -A --login-path=local -A
```

Which gave me this error:

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'login-path=local'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the order of the parameters

First Version:

```
mysql -NBA --login-path=my_credentials
```

failed with

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'login-path=my_credentials'
```

This could be solved with

```
mysql --login-path=my_credentials -NBA
```